# JQuery mobile validation not working i.e. not showing validation messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate this form :

```
<form id="manage-form" data-ajax="false">

<label for="business_Name" >Business Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="required" name="business_Name" id="business_Name" data-mini="true"/>



<input id="submission" type="submit" value="insert"/>

</form>
```

AND THIS JAVASCRIPT:

```
var amandeepdb;

$(document).ready(function(){

amandeepdb = openDatabase('AAFeedbackdb','1.0','AAFeedbackdb','2*1024*1024');


createTable();
insertAAType();


$("#submission").on("click", function (evt){


    handleAddForm();
    return false;
});

});

function handleAddForm(){

$('#manage-form').validate({ 
    rules: {
        business_Name: {
            required: true,
            rangelength:[2,30]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        business_Name: {
            required: "required",
            rangelength : "between 2 to 30"
        }
    }


});
}
```

IT IS NOT VALIDATING WHEN I AM CLICKING THE INSERT BUTTON i.e. NOT SHOWING THE MESSAGES.
The page just refreshes and doesn't show the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"The page just refreshes and doesn't show the message."*

It's not validating because you are not properly *initializing* the plugin.  Since you put the `.validate()` method within a `click` handler, the plugin is not initialized until *after* the click... by that time it's too late.

You should never need to call `.validate()` within a function, click handler, etc.

```
// the click handler is not needed - delete this...
//$("#submission").on("click", function (evt){
//    handleAddForm();
//    return false;
//});
```

Simply placing `.validate()` within the DOM ready handler will properly initialize the plugin.  Then the plugin will *automatically* capture the click of the submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#manage-form').validate({  // initializes the plugin
        // your rules and options
    });

});
```

Use `pageinit` for jQuery Mobile "ready" event...

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){

    $('#manage-form').validate({  // initializes the plugin
        // your rules and options
    });

});
```